# Base form must really be compiled as a class library rather than a simple form?

Tags: c#, winforms, oop, inheritance

I created a form (named BaseForm) that I want to use as...well, you know.

I then tried to get another form to inherit from it this way:

```
public partial class FormThatShouldInheritFromBaseForm : BaseForm {
```

...and even this way:

```
public partial class FormThatShouldInheritFromBaseForm : <MyProjectsNamespace>.BaseForm {
```

...but I get, "The type or namespace name 'BaseForm' does not exist in the namespace 'TitanNextGen_Worker' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

Comment: Is the base form is declared in another project? If so, add a project reference to the project that uses it. (Which is exactly what the compiler message is telling you)

Comment: No, the base form is in the same project.

Comment: Have you messed with the namespaces? Make sure the namespaces in the form's cs and Designer.cs files match.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that sometimes you have to compile the project before you can get inheritence to work.

Comment: catch 22/chicken-and-egg: it won't compile.

Comment: comment out the inheritence/remove the inheriting form, compile, add back what you removed.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to what I think your question is, is no. You can inherit from Forms in another assembly if it is compiled as a Windows Application (or any project type).

Which begs the question; are you in fact just missing an assembly reference in your derived form's project? :-)

Comment: This form is in the same project. I have BaseForm and Form2, let's call it. I simply want Form2 to inherit from BaseForm rather than Form.

Comment: Then, unless something else is wrong, this should work fine. Try excluding DerviedForm from the codebase, compile the project, and check that there isn't some other build error throwing up red herrings.
Another thing you could try is to remove DerivedForm, and create a new one in your project specifically selecting an 'Inherited Form' from the Add-->New Item menu.

Comment: Another thing to double check; have you referenced the correct namespace for BaseForm (e.g; it wasn't actually created under 'TitanNextGen_Worker.Forms' or something similar?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the second attempt isn't even valid C#, but yes, if the type resides in an external assembly you need to build it before you can use it in the main project.

If it doesn't reside in an external assembly then check your namespace and make sure they are both declared in the same one.

Comment: Why do you say the second attempt isn't valid C#? That's actually the example I found on msdn; however, since my base from is in the same namespace as the second form, I didn't think it necessary, but tried it "for grimaces" after the first attempt failed epic[al]ly. Both forms are in the same folder of the same solution/project and share the same namespace.

Comment: @ClayShannon I think Ed S means literal `<MyProjectsNamespace>` while you meant it as placeholder

Comment: I thouht <> was commonly recognized as bounding a placeholder.

Comment: Besides, who's going to name their project's namespace "MyProjectsNamespace"?